# Trouble creating JavaScript object from different file

Tags: javascript, html, object, paperjs

I have looked through some answers here and none have helped.
I'm new to javascript and I am trying to create a new object with some data from inside a script tag in an HTML document, and the object is defined in another file.

relevant information in HTML file: (this is all in the `<head>` tag)

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="data.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="paper-full.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="howler.core.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="circles.css">
<script type="text/paperscript" canvas="myCanvas">

    var keyData = new Data();

    function onKeyDown(event) {
        var colour = "orange";
        if(keyData.data[event.key]){
            keyData.data[event.key].sound.play();
            colour = keyData.data[event.key].colour;
        }
    }

</script>
```

my data.js file:

```
function Data(){
    var data = {
    q: {
        sound: new Howl({
        src: ['sounds/bubbles.mp3'],
        volume: 0.3
        }),
        colour: '#1abc9c'
    },
    w: {
        sound: new Howl({
        src: ['sounds/clay.mp3'],
        volume: 0.3
        }),
        colour: '#2ecc71'
    }, ... LOTS MORE DATA
...
}
```

Whenever I press a key on my keyboard I get an error in the chrome developer console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'e' of undefined
at Tool.onKeyDown [as _onKeyDown] (<anonymous>:11:38)
at Tool.emit (paper-full.js:662)
at emit (paper-full.js:12866)
at CanvasView._handleKeyEvent (paper-full.js:12874)
at handleKey (paper-full.js:13120)
at HTMLDocument.keypress (paper-full.js:13148)
```

which looks strange to me since it appears to be saying that 'e' is a property when it should be a key.

I'm new to JavaScript so I'm not too confident in splitting code into multiple files.

bonus: if someone could explain to me how to move my text/paperscript script to a separate file and not break everything that would be fantastic.

Thanks.

Comment: `var data` - change this to `this.data`

Comment: Properties = keys. There is no difference in JS.

Comment: changing to this.data worked, thanks!

Comment: and I suppose I was mixing up "properties" and "values" then